# Getting HTML value in PHP using AJAX and POST method

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I should start off by saying that I am very new to server side programming. I am trying to get a value on its change using AJAX.

My AJAX code (ajaxCode.php)

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
        $('select[name="selectBox"]').change(function(){
            var value = $(this).val();
            $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: 'calculator.php', 
                    data: {valueChange: value },
                    dataType: 'html'
            });
            alert(value );
        });
    });
```

My HTML code with the select box (calculator.php)

```
   <select name ="selectBox">   
        <option value="1">Value 1</option>
        <option value="2">Value 2</option>
        <option value="3">Value 3</option>
    </select> 

<?php
$status = $_POST['changeStatus'];
echo $status;
?>
```

This doesn't seem to work. The status will alert but won't be echoed. What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance?

Comment: But... but... you already have that selectBox in your DOM, but you also echo it in your calculator.php. ¿What do you expect to happen?

Comment: Should I place my PHP code in a separate file?

Comment: Remember, PHP runs first to generate the client side page, then the page is sent to the user. What your code is doing is generating a new page with the echo at the bottom of it (the response to your AJAX, which you don't do anything with).

Comment: You're trying to alert the value after a synchronous call. Use an asynchronous call:
https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/ajax_ajax.asp

Comment: What would be the proper way to handle such a request? In terms of file structure. Should the Ajax code be inside my calculator.php file

Comment: wrong line: data: {valueChange: value }, need add changeStatus

Comment: {changeStatus: value},

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to send value of selected box through ajax and then change the status which you get from ajax.

Server site: calculator.php

Client side:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('select[name="selectBox"]').change(function(){
        var value = $(this).val();
        $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'calculator.php', 
                data: {valueChange: value },
                dataType: 'html'
        }).done(function(response){
           $('.response-holder').html(response);
        });
    });
});
</script>

<select name ="selectBox">   
    <option value="1">Value 1</option>
    <option value="2">Value 2</option>
    <option value="3">Value 3</option>
</select> 
<div class="response-holder"></div>
```

Comment: yes. this is exactly what I answered. Somehow it got too extensive in my answer and it turns out yours is much clearer and understandable for OP.

Comment: So now the select box value is in the client-side's "response-holder", and I can get this value through _POST or _GET into another php document, correct?

Comment: @JonGoe In the "response-holder" you will have everything echoed from calculator.php. Through _POST or _GET you will get what's selected in selectbox.

Comment: This seems like the solution most appropriate to my problem, but I am having issue implementing it. I may have some major misconception of how SS is handled. My HTML file contains the code you provided above. I added in the div tag `method="post"`. In calculator.php, I simply get the value of the class through `<?php
$status = $_POST['response-holder'];
echo $status;
?>`. However, I am told that in the php doc, response-holder is not defined. Why does this happen? Thank you.

Comment: You need to change `$_POST['response-holder']` to `$_POST['valueChange']`

Comment: I'm glad I could help :)

Answer (score 1):

This works ok:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">     
      $(document).ready(function() {
           $(document).on("change", ".selectBox", function(){
                var v = $(this).val();
                $.post( "ajax.php", { changeStatus: v , time: "123" }, function( data ) {   
                    alert("From file: " +data);             
                });                 
            });
        });
    </script>   
</head>
<body>
<select name ="selectBox" class="selectBox">   
    <option value="1">Value 1</option>
    <option value="2">Value 2</option>
    <option value="3">Value 3</option>
</select> 
</body>
</html>
```

and ajax.php

```
<?php
$status = $_POST['changeStatus'];
echo $status;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The code that receives the ajax call should be in its own file, and echo only what you need to retrieve, not the whole content you started with. For example, just echo the status.

Let's say this is your HTML

```
<select name ="selectBox">   
    <option value="1">Value 1</option>
    <option value="2">Value 2</option>
    <option value="3">Value 3</option>
</select> 

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('select[name="selectBox"]').change(function(){
        var value = $(this).val();
        $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'calculator.php', 
                data: {valueChange: value },
                dataType: 'html'
        });
        alert(value );
    });
});
<script>
```

Then this *could* be your calculator.php

```
<?php
    $status = $_POST['changeStatus'];
    echo $status;
?>
```

But then, again, you're making an ajax call and not doing anything with its response. To receive that calculator.php is answering, you could do

```
<select name ="selectBox">   
    <option value="1">Value 1</option>
    <option value="2">Value 2</option>
    <option value="3">Value 3</option>
</select> 
<div id="response"></div>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('select[name="selectBox"]').change(function(){
        var value = $(this).val();
        $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'calculator.php', 
                data: {valueChange: value },
                dataType: 'html'
        }).then(function(response) {
           jQuery('#response').html('Ajax answered: '+response);
        });
        alert(value );
    });
});
<script>
```

Comment: I am using the PHP code in calculator.php and the HTML+AJAX in htmlCal.html. When choosing an option, the value is alerted but changeStatus is undefined in the PHP file. Why could this be? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your calculator.php script.

```
<?php
    $status = $_POST['valueChange'];
    echo $status;
?>
```

Does this give you your desired result?